# Woocommerce single product page not working

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I'm working on a new webshop, everything was working fine and the shop was almost done. Today I did some tweeks to the search page and some styling changes, but now I noticed that the single product page isn't working anymore. The shop, cart, category page and everything else from woocommerce is working just fine, except for the single product page.

I did do an update to v5.5.2 today, maybe that has something to do with this, but I can't figure out how to fix this.

As you can see in the screenshot below, the product image, pricing, options etc. isn't showing up, only the description.

[Woocommerce single page with DOM](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QCLKL.png)

Does anyone here know how this could have happend and how I can fix this?

**Details:**

WP v5.8

Woocommerce v5.5.2

Comment: You should sheck with other theme or you can temporary inactive plugin one by one and check for that you can more investigate more about issue.

Answer (score 0):

Is your theme and plugins running on the latest version?

If you temporarily switch to another theme (example twenty-twentyone) and you try to open the same product page is it working properly?

Comment: When I switched to a different theme, the single product pages works again, I made a custom theme from scratch and all the plugins are running on the latest version.

Do you know what could cause this to not work with my own theme (which worked perfectly a few days ago) ?

Comment: Obviously that means that the problem is in your theme and not some plugin or wp updated version. Maybe try to restore some previous working settings you used on your theme or code.